# What is the use of 'Cost' attribute in Catalog product in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have read the magento document for it and found that this is the actual cost of the item.

http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/settings-advanced-advanced-pricing.html

Cost:  **The actual cost of the item**. (Where it is used ?) (What is purpose of it?)

[image: cost attribute image]

Looking forward to this great community to get more details about its uses.

Any directions or details are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Check http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5874/cogs-cost-of-goods-sold-tracking-in-magento

Comment: Thanks Sohel ! As per magento2 docs, Cost in advance pricing is about the 'cost price' for that item. 
What i wanted to know is 'which module and which class has used this attribute'? OR is it reserved for future use?

Answer (score 1):

For 'cost' attribute, there are no calculation class for it like as other price. But it's save into quote and order item table.

Following class responsible to save quote when 'add to cart'.
**Magento/Quote/Model/Quote/Item.php**

```
/**
 * Setup product for quote item
 *
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
 * @return $this
 */
public function setProduct($product)
{
    if ($this->getQuote()) {
        $product->setStoreId($this->getQuote()->getStoreId());
        $product->setCustomerGroupId($this->getQuote()->getCustomerGroupId());
    }
    $this->setData('product', $product)
        ->setProductId($product->getId())
        ->setProductType($product->getTypeId())
        ->setSku($this->getProduct()->getSku())
        ->setName($product->getName())
        ->setWeight($this->getProduct()->getWeight())
        ->setTaxClassId($product->getTaxClassId())
        ->setBaseCost($product->getCost());

    $stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItem($product->getId(), $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
    $this->setIsQtyDecimal($stockItem->getIsQtyDecimal());

    $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
        'sales_quote_item_set_product',
        ['product' => $product, 'quote_item' => $this]
    );

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

cost attribute is available for simple and all the product types in Magento, it will make much easier to assign a cost price as well as sell price so you can manage profitability a lot easier.
You can enable it to make it visible for front end too. see [this video](https://youtu.be/qbHhEcNENUQ)

Comment: Thanks for this information. Do you know any module or class where it is used in magento2? I am searching it but couldn't find out.

Comment: Most useless answer. I don't think he knows himself what the cost field is used for.

Answer (score 0):

"Cost of Goods Sold" has same meaning as attribute "cost" in magento2

Read details in this link. 
http://newsgento.com/why-is-cost-of-goods-sold-data-important-to-my-magento-store/

Excerpt from this link

> **Basics of Cost of Goods Sold and Gross Margin**
>   First, let’s review some basic economic terms. Cost of Goods Sold refers to the amount of money used to either produce a product, or to purchase a product for resale. If your ecommerce store purchases raw materials that are used to make your products, the cost of your raw materials, plus the cost of assembling your product, equals your Cost of Goods Sold.

Hope it will help to understand this attribute.

Comment: Thanks for this detail, But read clearly what i have asked. I asked the reference to the magento2 code where it is used.

Answer (score -1):

1- Used for Admin Reference: so far I found one use for the Cost attribute which is to inform the Admin about the cost of a certain item given that the Admin has previously entered that piece of data.

2- In reporting, to calculate COGS and profit margin and other accounting stuff.

I'm not sure if this kind of reporting is available natively in Magento or through a third-party module. Totally depends on your setup and your Advanced Reporting settings and if you have integrations like New Relic or Magento Business Intelligence etc.