# Magento2 Use of "Cost" In Catalog Product Edit Advanced Pricing Section

Tags: magento2, product, catalog

Does anyone explain me what is the use of "Cost" Attribute in magento 2 catalog product edit advanced pricing section?

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked before.

[What is the use of 'Cost' attribute in Catalog product in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/157262/what-is-the-use-of-cost-attribute-in-catalog-product-in-magento-2)

Answer:

It's saved to the quote and to other documents. The (purchase)cost of an item can go up or down, Because of this, the gross margin can be calculated per product even when the order is a few months old.